# Accessing caller class attribute

Tags: java

I would like to know if it is possible from a child class to get caller attributes. Follow a sample.

TestClass1.class

```
package test;

public class TestClass1 {
    
    private String myTestClass1Var = "xxxxx";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestClass1().class2();
    }
    
    private void class2() {
        new TestClass2().getClass1Attributes();
    }
}
```

TestClass2.class

```
package test;

public class TestClass2 {

    public void getClass1Attributes() {
        //is something like this possible? 
        getCaller().myTestClass1Var
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: it's not a child-class, just a called class. yes, and no. the way you are doing it right now, no. But, you can pass an instance of the calling class as parameter to the getClass1Attributes, and just call it as: new TestClass2().getClass1Attributes(this);

Comment: Hello @Stultuske thanks for you reply. So if I understood correctly means that without pass the caller as a parameter wont be possible to access caller class data, correct ?

Comment: you can only use data which exists in the scope you are in. so unless you have access to that specific instance of that class, you can't reach it's fields

Comment: Do you mind to mention about youe objectives? Do you want to create a hierarchical class with inheritance? What's purpose?